# Problem with Python Code for finding length between two strings in a text file

Tags: python, sequence

Hello I am quite new to python and started taking classes for biologists but I have a problem with an assignment in python and just can't figure it out. From a .txt file i should find 2 restriction enzymes (basically just letters), "gatc" with an g or a in front and c or t in the back so: "[ga]gatc[ct]". This is 2 times in the text file and i should find out the length between them(xxxx[ga]gatc[ct] xxxxxxx [ga]gatc[ct]xxxx) -->how many x are between them . I tried to put it in groups but i make something wrong.
xxxx is an unknown number of letters that is made up of "g" "a" "t" "c" : like ctactatctcatcttaaccttaa for example

My current code is:

```
import regex
file = "enzyme.txt"
f=open(file, "r")
content = f.read()
print(content)
pattern = regex.compile("[ga]gatc[ct]")
for line in open("enzyme.txt"):
   for match in regex.finditer (pattern, line):
        print(match.group())
        print(line)
for lines in f:
    m=regex.search("[ga]gatc[ct] {*} [ga]gatc[ct]", lines)
    if m:
        print(len(str(m.start(1)) + str(m.end(2))))
```

it shows me the correct sequence and prints the line in which it is but i don't know how to find the length in between them. the second part of the code doesn't do anything but also shows no error message.

Comment: Firstly, are the patterns limited to one line, or are you looking for xxxx that spans multiple lines?  Or are you trying to find the number of lines between two gatc's? Secondly, is gagatcct a valid find, or you need only gagatc and gatcct sequences?

Comment: yes xxxx spans over multiple lines. and it should find a gatc with either a "g" or "a" in front and a "c" or "t" at the end of gatc (so there are 4 possible combinations). I would like to find the length of how many letters are between the 2 findings.

Comment: What about gagatcxxxxxgagatctZZZZZgagatcXXXXgagatc -- do yo uneed to count only "x"es and X'es, or also Z's?

Comment: yes but the x i just put as a placeholder they are the letters: g,a,c,t in random order. so no z's and no x's. but all are lower case letters. It is like imagining a rope and a few parts are blue and the rest is red. Now you cut out all blue parts (gagatc) and now are left with the red parts (random g,a,t,c letters) and you measure how many red parts  you have and how long they are.

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective this will be a naive solution.

```
pattern = "[ga]gatc[ct]"

with open("enzyme.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        parsed = line.split(pattern)[1]
        print(len(parsed))
```

1. `str.split` will divide the line into pieces according to given pattern
2. IN your case the pattern will be `[ga]gatc[ct]`
3. Now you need to access the index `1` for the `xxxxxxxx` because index `0` will be `''`. An empty string.
4. Now you wanted the length of text in between the pattern so, `print(len(parsed))`

Comment: thank you sorry i think i have written it not very exact in my description so there is also an unknown number of letters before and after the pattern so xxxxxxxx[ga]gatc[ct]xxxxxxxxxx[ga]gatc[ct]xxxxxxxx the text file hase like 6000 letters of "g" "c" "a" "t" but the pattern only is in it twice.